# want to dynamically resize columns in Vaadin table

Tags: java, css, vaadin

My Vaadin table looks like this when first displayed:

[image: first image]

Note that the longer numbers in the last three columns are cut off. If I move the line between, say, 1 Year and 2 Year, the long numbers display correctly, that is, they are right-aligned in that column. The program does not set any sizes of any columns. So my first question is how to create the table (or add the data) properly so it allows enough space.

If I click on "More stuff" it looks like this:

[image: second image]

The additional information in the last three columns is truncated because it is longer than the info already there. So my second question is how to have the table lay itself out again so that it has enough space for its content.

I do not know the widths of the data to go in these columns ahead of time; I do not want to set pixel values in the program if I can get the width from the data instead. It seems there is some provision for this, since the 2nd column is wider to accommodate its wider data with no help from the program.

The classes involved are below:

TableUI2

```
package com.mycompany.vaadin3;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.data.Property;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Alignment;
import com.vaadin.ui.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Layout;
import com.vaadin.ui.OptionGroup;
import com.vaadin.ui.Table;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.themes.ValoTheme;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@Theme("mytheme")
public class TableUI2 extends UI{

    private static String COL1      = "Col 1";
    private static String COL2      = "Col 2";
    private static String COL3      = "Col 3";
    private static String TERM1     = "1 Year";
    private static String TERM2     = "2 Year";
    private static String TERM3     = "3 Year";

    private static String LESS_STUFF = "Less stuff";
    private static String MORE_STUFF = "More Stuff";

    private ResizableTable          table = null;
    private ArrayList<DataRow> rowList = null;
    private OptionGroup        moreOrLessOption = null;

    final private List<Label> hiddenLabels = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout pageLayout = new VerticalLayout();

        moreOrLessOption = createOptionGroup(); 

        Layout optionsPanelLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
        optionsPanelLayout.addComponents(moreOrLessOption);

        rowList = new DataLoader().getRowList();
        table = createTable(rowList);

        pageLayout.addComponents(optionsPanelLayout, table);

        setContent(pageLayout);
    }

    private OptionGroup createOptionGroup()
    {
        OptionGroup newGroup = new OptionGroup("");
        newGroup.setMultiSelect(false);
        newGroup.addItems(LESS_STUFF, MORE_STUFF);
        newGroup.addValueChangeListener
            ( new Property.ValueChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event)
                    {
                        // depending on the value of the option, show more or less
                        boolean showMore = getShowMore(newGroup);
                        for (Label label: hiddenLabels)
                        {
                            label.setVisible(showMore);
                        }
                        table.setColumnWidth(COL1, -1);
                        table.setColumnWidth(COL2, -1);
                        table.setColumnWidth(COL3, -1);
                    }
                }
            );
        return newGroup;
    }

    private boolean getShowMore(OptionGroup mrcOption) throws RuntimeException
    {
        boolean result = false;
        String value = mrcOption.getValue().toString();
        switch(value)
        {
            case "Less stuff": break;
            case "More Stuff": result = true; break;
            default: throw new RuntimeException("OOPS! -- illegal mrcOption value");
        }
        return result;
    }

    private ResizableTable createTable(ArrayList<DataRow> rowList)
    {
        ResizableTable newTable = createNewTable();

        int listIndex = 0;
        for (DataRow row : rowList)
        {
            VerticalLayout c1 = getVerticalLayout(row.getBandwidth());
            VerticalLayout c2   = getVerticalLayout(row.getService());
            VerticalLayout c3  = getVerticalLayout(row.getProvider());
            List<Layout> termLayouts = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i=1; i<=3; i++)
            {
                Layout termLayout = getTermLayout(1, row, hiddenLabels);
                termLayouts.add(termLayout);
            }

            newTable.addItem
                    (new Object[]
                        { 
                            c1,
                            c2,
                            c3,
                            termLayouts.get(0),
                            termLayouts.get(1),
                            termLayouts.get(2)
                        },
                        listIndex++
                    );
        }
        return newTable;
    }

    private VerticalLayout getVerticalLayout(String s)
    {
        VerticalLayout vl = new VerticalLayout();
        Label l = new Label(s);
        l.setSizeUndefined();
        vl.addComponents(l);
        vl.setComponentAlignment(l,Alignment.TOP_LEFT);
        return vl;
    }

    private Layout getTermLayout(int term, DataRow row, List<Label> costLabels)
    {
        // get charge data
        String charge = null;
        switch (term)
        {
            case 1: charge = row.getOneYearMRCCharge(); break;
            case 2: charge = row.getOneYearMRCCharge(); break;
            case 3: charge = row.getOneYearMRCCharge(); break;
        }
        Label chargeLabel = new Label(charge);

        // get cost data
        String cost = null;
        switch (term)
        {
            case 1: cost = row.getOneYearMRCCost(); break;
            case 2: cost = row.getOneYearMRCCost(); break;
            case 3: cost = row.getOneYearMRCCost(); break;
        }
        String percentage = getPercentage(cost, charge);
        String costString = String.format("(%s) %s", percentage, cost);
        Label costLabel = new Label(costString);
        costLabel.setVisible(false);
        costLabel.addStyleName("pricingtablecost");
        costLabels.add(costLabel);      // put in list so we can hide/reveal it later.

        VerticalLayout result = new VerticalLayout();
        result.setSizeFull();
        result.addComponents(chargeLabel, costLabel);
        chargeLabel.setSizeUndefined();
        costLabel.setSizeUndefined();
        result.setComponentAlignment(chargeLabel, Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);
        result.setComponentAlignment(costLabel, Alignment.TOP_RIGHT);

        return result;
    }

    private String getPercentage(String numerator, String denominator)
    {
        double num = Double.parseDouble(numerator);
        double denom = Double.parseDouble(denominator);
        double percentage = (denom - num) / denom * 100;
        String pString = String.format("%5.1f%%", percentage);
        return pString;
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = TableUI2.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    private ResizableTable createNewTable()
    {
        table = new ResizableTable();
        table.setSelectable(true);
        table.setImmediate(true);
        table.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABLE_COMPACT);
        table.addStyleName(ValoTheme.TABLE_NO_HORIZONTAL_LINES);
        table.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
        table.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);
        table.setPageLength(0);         // no scrolling for table alone.

        table.addContainerProperty(COL1, Layout.class, null);
        table.addContainerProperty(COL2, Layout.class, null);
        table.addContainerProperty(COL3, Layout.class, null);
        table.addContainerProperty(TERM1, Layout.class, null);
        table.addContainerProperty(TERM2, Layout.class, null);
        table.addContainerProperty(TERM3, Layout.class, null);
        table.setColumnAlignment(COL1,  Table.Align.CENTER);
        table.setColumnAlignment(TERM1, Table.Align.RIGHT);
        table.setColumnAlignment(TERM2, Table.Align.RIGHT);
        table.setColumnAlignment(TERM3, Table.Align.RIGHT);
        table.setColumnWidth(COL1, -1);
        table.setColumnWidth(COL2, -1);
        table.setColumnWidth(COL3, -1);
        table.setColumnWidth(TERM1, -1);
        table.setColumnWidth(TERM2, -1);
        table.setColumnWidth(TERM3, -1);

        return table;
    }

}
```

DataLoader

```
package com.mycompany.vaadin3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author rcook
 */
public class DataLoader {

    public ArrayList<DataRow> getRowList()
    {
        ArrayList<DataRow> rowList         = new ArrayList<>();
        rowList.add(new DataRow("ABCDE", "This thing",  "one two",          "326.91", "175.76" ));
        rowList.add(new DataRow("",     "",             "four five six",    "1514.11", "282.48"));
        rowList.add(new DataRow("FGHIJ",     "This thing",   "seven eight", "523.29", "287.52"));
        rowList.add(new DataRow("",     "",             "nine ten",         "2926.20", "520.33"));
        return rowList;
    }

}
```

DataRow:

```
package com.mycompany.vaadin3;

public class DataRow {
    private String bandwidth;
    private String provider;

    private String oneYearMRCCharge;
    private String oneYearMRCCost;

    private String service;  

    public String getBandwidth() {
        return bandwidth;
    }

    public void setBandwidth(String bandwidth) {
        this.bandwidth = bandwidth;
    }

    public String getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    public void setProvider(String provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public String getOneYearMRCCharge() {
        return oneYearMRCCharge;
    }

    public void setOneYearMRCCharge(String oneYearMRCCharge) {
        this.oneYearMRCCharge = oneYearMRCCharge;
    }

    public String getOneYearMRCCost() {
        return oneYearMRCCost;
    }

    public void setOneYearMRCCost(String oneYearMRCCost) {
        this.oneYearMRCCost = oneYearMRCCost;
    }

    public String getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(String service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public DataRow() {}

    public DataRow(String bandwidth, String provider, String service, String charge, String cost) {
        setBandwidth(bandwidth);
        setOneYearMRCCharge(charge);
        setOneYearMRCCost(cost);
        setProvider(provider);
        setService(service);
    }

}
```

ResizableTable -- one of the things I tried was firing a propertySetChange, but that didn't work.

```
package com.mycompany.vaadin3;

import com.vaadin.ui.Table;

/**
 * @author rcook
 */
public class ResizableTable extends Table {
    public void resize() { firePropertySetChange(); }
}
```

Comment: In short: You have to set the width's yourself. The table trys to do some calculations based on the initial data visible. But when you table overall width is too small, it has to clip some columns. When you then afterwards change the data/columns, you have to set the sizes yourself

Comment: Try calling table.refreshRowCache(); this may make the table sort it self out.